# How to increase the network utilization in Amazon EC2?, will the process priority change would help to improve it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need a guidance on how I can improve my network utilization of a process inside my Amazon EC2 Server. Now it seems the network utilization is around 7%. If we change the priority for the particular process would help?

Comment: Is your CPU at a maximum ?  What's your load average? Whatever you need to do to increase the Network Utilization will depend on what resources you may be saturating.

Comment: What size instance do you have? all the smaller instances are on multi-tenant hardware and will share network with other instances.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all.  The network utilization is "7%" of what?  Where do you see this value?  What is the actual problem you are experiencing?

Comment: +1 @Rico. And although this is merely a guess, the most common scenario is that your cpu really isn't saturated, as Rico suggests, and that adding more processes/threads will help. (I am guessing a basic web app here). Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the bottleneck is. It could be CPU, disk, file handles, etc.

If you are on a micro instance, you most certainly will want to move up to a "real" instance. They are under-powered for multi-user stuff.